# Add text line in Invoice PDF

Tags: magento-1.8, invoice, pdf

I would like to add a new text line in the footer in the PDF invoice.

But where can I do this?

Comment: goto Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16439/magento-invoice-pdf-design-customization