# How to can I add some text in invoice pdf magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf

[image]

Image showing lower part of pdf.

I want to change invoice pdf.

I want some text on left side.

And below grand total I want to show line for signiture.

How can I achieve this please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoice Pdf is created by `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice` model

So you either have to directly make changes to `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.pdf` (really not recommended)

or
overwrite this by copying this file to the same directory strtucture in local folder (not the best option)

or
create an extension that overwrites the specific model (the best and safest way to achieve it)

you can see here as well:
[magento: invoice PDF design customization](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16439/magento-invoice-pdf-design-customization)

Comment: @Jatin FYI The file is located at app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php