# Magento : Add Default Note in Invoice PDF

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf

How to add default note to bottom of Invoice PDF or add default image?

Comment: May I whether you would like to  add the logo in the invoice pdf?  http://prntscr.com/fbybqq

Comment: please check this link might be useful for you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16439/magento-invoice-pdf-design-customization